# Custom contact reference field with "New Organization"

Tags: custom-fields, relationships

I would like to create a custom contact reference field (for CiviGrants) that also has the ability to add a new contact on the fly. It should be like the default Contact field used in (for example) Contributions or Grants. Any help would be appreciated... Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This feature request would, IMO, be a good match for the [paid issue queue](https://civicrm.org/paid-issue-queue). Giving custom contact reference fields the option to have "create new" functionality would be a nice addition to CiviCRM.

Comment: Thanks Coleman. Do you have an idea how much work this would be? I need to go back to my client with options.

Comment: Probably in the ballpark of 10 hours. If you want to pursue further you can fill out the paid issue queue quote request form.